# Angular application with Node + Express web API returning JSON resources vs server side template engine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug

I'm quite new to Node and Express and I'm having some difficulties understanding the concept of server side rendering with template engines (like Jade) or without.

My experience with web development is solely based on Angular applications which consume resources in a JSON format from a RESTful Web API and render the html using Angular's two-way data binding.

What are the pros and cons of this approach, and what are the benefits of rendering html pages on the server when there's so much flexibility with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-tradeoffs-of-client-side-rendering-vs-server-side-rendering) is the best description I've found when digging into the topic for several months.

But let me answer your question from the height of my experience:

1. These approaches are **not mutually exclusive** to each over, but are complementary.
2. Pros of server-side rendering:

   - very speedy **initial** loading of pages (use AJAX/MVC for subsequent updates);
   - good for SEO.
3. Cons:

   - it may be a bit difficult to set it up initially.
4. I'd recommend you to build your app in a traditional Angular way, and only add the server-side rendering if you feel your app is slow to respond.